# Module doesn't define an attribute/class

Tags: python, database, django, django-settings

I want to write a multi-table application on Django, so I created two databases, one of them to use by default, other - *"map"* to use by specific app - *"map"*.

*map/models.py:*

```
from django.db import models
class MapRouter(object):
   def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
               if model._meta.app_label == 'map':
                       return 'map'
               return None
   def db_for_write(self, model, **hints): 
               if model._meta.app_label == 'map':
                       return 'map'
               return None
   def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
               if obj1._meta.app_label == 'map' or \
                  obj2._meta.app_label == 'map':
                  return True
               return None
   def allow_migrate(self, db, model):
               if db == 'map':
                       return model._meta.app_label == 'map'
               elif model._meta.app_label == 'map':
                       return False
               return None
```

*settings.py:*

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'eventmap',
       'USER': 'eventmap',
       'PASSWORD': 'eventmap',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '',
   },
   'map': {
       'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
       'NAME': 'map',
       'USER': 'eventmap',
       'PASSWORD': 'eventmap',
       'HOST': 'localhost',
       'PORT': '',
   }
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['map.MapRouter']
```

The problem is when I run **`python manage.py syncdb`** it says:

> *django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Module "map" does not define a "MapRouter" attribute/class*

What's wrong with it?

Comment: I don't know django well enough, but "map" is a builtin function. I suspect its imported rather than the module you want. Don't name modules after built in functions!

Comment: I've changed this name to _"mymap"_, but still have this exception(

Comment: does that app have an `__init__.py` file ?

Comment: In the mymap directory, do you have a `__init__.py` and does it `from models import MapRouter`? Maybe there is other django magic, but map.MapRouter doesn't exist unless your `__init__.py` makes it so.

Comment: Yes, it have that file and all other files that are common for django apps

Comment: for some reason __init__.py is empty but exists

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the full path to your router in the setting.

```
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['map.models.MapRouter']
```